# Sorting Arrays creating key value pairs from multiple sources

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have a large JSON array that I want to use to create key value pairs, combining 3 integers as one pair item and another integer for the second pair item.

I am a begginer in coding so looking for some good advice along the way. The purpose of the code is to integrate in to my automation setup.

Im trying to put showid, season and episode as one combined integer and the episodeid and the key value pair.

So for the example below :

newarray = [{7.2.1 : 272, 7.2.2 : 273}]

2 objects within the array are as follows :

```
[
  {
    "episodes": [
      {
        "art": {
          "season.banner": "image://.jpg/",
          "season.poster": "image://.jpg/",
          "season.thumb": "image:.tbn/",
          "tvshow.banner": ".jpg/",
          "tvshow.fanart": "image:jpg/",
          "tvshow.poster": "image:jpg/"
        },
        "episode": 1,
        "episodeid": 272,
        "file": "test.avi",
        "label": "test1",
        "originaltitle": "",
        "playcount": 0,
        "plot": Hello World",
        "rating": 8,
        "season": 2,
        "thumbnail": "image.tbn/",
        "title": "test1",
        "tvshowid": 7
      },
      {
        "art": {
          "season.banner": "image://.jpg/",
          "season.poster": "image://.jpg/",
          "season.thumb": "image:.tbn/",
          "tvshow.banner": ".jpg/",
          "tvshow.fanart": "image:jpg/",
          "tvshow.poster": "image:jpg/"
        },
        "episode": 2,
        "episodeid": 273,
        "file": "test1.avi",
        "label": "test1",
        "originaltitle": "",
        "playcount": 0,
        "plot": Hello World",
        "rating": 8,
        "season": 2,
        "thumbnail": "image1.tbn/",
        "title": "test2",
        "tvshowid": 7
      },
]
```

I have tried to sort using push but its too basic for my needs. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `map` over each show, then `map` over each episode, then use a template string to create the key of each object:

```js
shows = [{
  "episodes": [
    {"episode": 1, "episodeid": 272, "season": 2, "tvshowid": 7 },
    {"episode": 2, "episodeid": 273, "season": 2, "tvshowid": 7 }
  ]
}]

const mapped = shows.map(show => show.episodes.map(o => ({
  [`${o.tvshowid}.${o.season}.${o.episode}`]: o.episodeid
})))

console.log(mapped)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a reducer to get the an array of relations:

```js
const collection =
  {
    "episodes": [
      {
        "art": {
          "season.banner": "image://.jpg/",
          "season.poster": "image://.jpg/",
          "season.thumb": "image:.tbn/",
          "tvshow.banner": ".jpg/",
          "tvshow.fanart": "image:jpg/",
          "tvshow.poster": "image:jpg/"
        },
        "episode": 1,
        "episodeid": 272,
        "file": "test.avi",
        "label": "test1",
        "originaltitle": "",
        "playcount": 0,
        "plot": "Hello World",
        "rating": 8,
        "season": 2,
        "thumbnail": "image.tbn/",
        "title": "test1",
        "tvshowid": 7
      },
      {
        "art": {
          "season.banner": "image://.jpg/",
          "season.poster": "image://.jpg/",
          "season.thumb": "image:.tbn/",
          "tvshow.banner": ".jpg/",
          "tvshow.fanart": "image:jpg/",
          "tvshow.poster": "image:jpg/"
        },
        "episode": 2,
        "episodeid": 273,
        "file": "test1.avi",
        "label": "test1",
        "originaltitle": "",
        "playcount": 0,
        "plot": "Hello World",
        "rating": 8,
        "season": 2,
        "thumbnail": "image1.tbn/",
        "title": "test2",
        "tvshowid": 7
      },
]
}

relations = collection.episodes.reduce((acc, curr) => {
 const relation = {[curr.tvshowid + '.' + curr.season + '.' + curr.episode]: curr.episodeid}
 acc = [...acc,relation];
 return acc;
},[])
console.log(relations)
```

Comment: If you are always returning an object with the same return type, use map, not reduce. Also, why would you destructure the acc just to append an item and return it? That's what `push` is for.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for creating a new array.

```
var newarray = oShows.episodes.map( function(o){
    return {[o.tvshowid + "." + o.season + "." + o.episode] : o.episodeid};
});

console.log(newarray);  //[{7.2.1: 272}, {7.2.2: 273}]
```

> Im trying to put showid, season and episode as one combined integer...

That's not possible because e.g. "7.2.1" is no integer. Your key will be a string.